# Do the power ratings on the nameplate of an AC motor indicate electrical or mechanical power?

Tags: power, motor, ac, induction-motor

A 6 pole 3-phase AC induction motor is delta-connected and has the following rated values on its nameplate:

- Frequency: 50 Hz
- Power: 22 kW   30 hp
- RPM: 970
- \$\cos \phi\$ (power factor): 0.80
- Primer voltage (\$V_{\text{line}}\$): 380 V
- Primer current (\$I_{\text{line}}\$): 47 A

Since the total power of a 3-phase AC induction motor when delta-connected is

$$ P_t = \sqrt{3} \cdot V_{\text{line}} \cdot I_{\text{line}} \cdot \cos \phi $$

I calculate the electrical power as

$$ P_t = 24.75 \;\mathrm{kW} $$

but on the nameplate there are two powers, written as 22 kW and 30 hp (30 hp is 22.37 kW); are they the same thing?

Why am I calculating the power \$P_t\$ differently? Are the power ratings on the nameplate mechanical power or electrical power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power that can be read on the name space is the **mechanical power** you can take from the shaft of the motor. What you calculated is the **electrical power** that you put in the motor. There has to be a difference due to mechanical/electrical losses (friction, heat etc.) in the motor.

Concerning the 30 hp: I think 1 hp = 736 W, so 30 hp =22080 Watts which is close enough to 22 kW.

**EDIT**

According to their formula: $$ HP = \frac{1,73* E *I * Eff*PF}{746} = \frac{1,73 * 380 V * 47 A * (\frac {22 kW}{24,75 kW}) * 0,8}{746} = 29,5 hp $$ That should be close enough to 30 hp.

Comment: i thought so, but please check out this link from a very trustable manufacturer: http://www.ab.com/support/abdrives/documentation/fb/1018.pdf if you look at carfully you see that kW and hp are diffrent things(efficiency makes the difference). thats why i was confused.

Comment: 736 W is "metric horsepower".  I never met a metric horse, though.  It's 746 W otherwise...go figure.

Comment: Technically, both hp and kW measure power. In Europe, they often specify mechanical power in W and kW rather than horsepower. The electrical power input to a motor is always higher than the mechanical power output due to efficiency being less than 100%. Basically, that whole entire sheet is telling you that power out = power in * efficiency. There is some other stuff dealing with power factor, also.

Comment: If you actually look at that link, you will also see that the difference is between INput power and OUTput power.  The efficiency is applied to the OUTput power.

Comment: Answer is correct. A 22kW motor produces 22kW of mechanical shaft power. Calculating volts × amps gives the electrical input power in kVA, which includes efficiency and power factor. </ Practicing electrical engineer>.